# Exception Wrapper for Service Layer

Tags: java, spring, architecture, exception

I´m creating a `@Component` that will be a Service Layer in one of our artifacts, I want to wrap all the possible exception coming from this new component into an specific artifact Exception (just for given a name it will be `ArtifactException`).

My question is how I can translate any exception that happens in this service layer or layers below to the `ArtifactException`.

I´m looking for more elegant solution than: (Catch and re-throw)

```
 catch (NamingException ex){
      //EXCEPTION WRAPPING
      throw new ArtifactException(
        "Config error with JNDI and datasource, for db " + Util.quote(dbConnString), ex
      );
    }
    catch (SQLException ex ){
      //EXCEPTION WRAPPING
      throw new ArtifactException(
       "Cannot get connection from datasource, for db " + Util.quote(dbConnString), ex
      );
    }
```

I was thinking in using  `@AfterThrowing` with aspects but I want to be out of aspects to keep this simple.

I know about `@ExceptionHandler` but this works with `DispatcherServlet` which are not implemented as we are working in the service layer, nothing to dowith spring-mvc

There is any other option to handle this using Spring?, perhaps a new annotation that I did not know or any other method.

I think what I'm looking is know as Exception Translator for Service Layer in Spring

Thanks.

Comment: No, aspects seems like the perfect solution. However, you wouldn't use  `@AfterThrowing`, you would use `@Around`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just want to wrap the exception if it happens, using AfterThrowing seems to fit perfect this requirement as it only execute if the service method throw any exception, using Around seems like a way to isolate the method execution, probably I can use a try catch inside and then rethrow my ArtifactException (seems like catch then rethrow), but if you could tell me why don't use AfterThrowing or why I choose Around, will be great, probably I'm not seeing something.

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking of `@AfterReturning`. `@AfterThrowing` is appropriate here.

Comment: Why do you think catching and rethrowing is inelegant?  To me, it seems a lot more elegant and clear in this case than using annotations.

Comment: @WarrenDew Imagine we have several methods with the same try catch blocks, it seems a lot of duplicate code. Obviously ypu can tell to me to refactor this logic of these try-catches blocks in a method, but at the end in each method in which I want this beahviour I should call this refactor method, not bad at all, but I was looking some {elegant} solution as the **@ExceptionHandler**, **@ApplicationException** that wraps any exception happens within method execution without make anything else. Anyway probably elegant is not the correct word it should be non-intrusive or something like that =P